# Two views, one model : How to update the views when the model changes

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, user-interface

I'm designing a Qt UI and have two different views ( `QGraphicsObject` class)  for the same model (a car).

When the car's model is to be updated (in one of two widgets), I want both of the views to be updated (and of course the same goes for the model).

The intuitive way to do this is to update the model, and let the views catch a 'signal' or something similar when this happens to update themselves.

I want to know if this is a recommended behavior (in MVC) as it forces the model to have some bidirectional connection with its views (while in MVC the model shouldn't have a list of its views).

Also, what's a good way to implement this in Qt ? (use Qt signals ? raise a flag when the model have been changed ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is your model going to look like? In Qt, there's a standard API for a list-like, table-like and tree-like models, the [model-view programming](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html). However, it doesn't play that well with `QGraphicsScene` which you're apparently using. You haven't said what you'd like to use for communication, or how is the data you're modelling structured, so it's hard to suggest what exactly you should do here.

That said, the usual MVC pattern (which mathes the `QAbstractItemModel` API used in Qt) is to let the model inform any attached views about any changes to the underlying data; in Qt, this is done via signals to which the views connect. When the views want to modify data, they call methods on the model. When the model accepts the modifications, it emits the standard signals so that all views are updated afterwards.

Comment: But how do I explicitely 'connect' a model to a view in Qt ? I actually just considered that my model is an attribute to my views (a custom ``QGraphicsObject`` ) ?

Comment: QAbstractItemModels can be connected to QAbstractItemView subclasses via setModel(). However, that's rather table/tree/list-specific. If you have less data and rather a couple of state variables you want to monitor (instead of lists etc.), a model wrapper QObject holding the state and sending out signals on changes might be better suited. There's no pattern to catch all use cases, it rather depends on your kind of model.